# How to drop the period character from custom item numbering when referencing the item?

Tags: lists, enumerate, labels, enumitem, ref

**Edit:** Code snippet extended to a complete working sample. It contains all the packages used in the actual document I'm working with.

I have a custom enumerate environment set up as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Font package
\usepackage{textcomp} % Package for special symbols
\usepackage[pdftex]{color, graphicx} % For pdf output and jpg/png graphics
\usepackage[pdftex, plainpages=false]{hyperref} % For hyperlinks and pdf metadata
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For nicer page headers
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} % For better math
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib} % For bibliography
\usepackage[footnotesize,bf]{caption} % For more control over figure captions
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% enumitem list setup
\newlist{pseudocode}{enumerate}{2}% allow two levels of nesting in an enumerate-like environment
\setlist[pseudocode]{nosep}% compact spacing for all nesting levels
\setlist[pseudocode,1]{label=\arabic*.}% labels for top level
\setlist[pseudocode,2]{label=\arabic{pseudocodei}\alph*.}% labels for second level
\begin{document}


\section{Pseudocode}
\begin{pseudocode}
  \item Initialization
  \begin{pseudocode}
    \item Initialization step \label{initStep1}
    \item Another initialization step
  \end{pseudocode}
  \item Loop
\end{pseudocode}

\section{What does it do?}
In initialization step \ref{initStep1}, the array is...
\end{document}
```

The last line produces:

In initialization step 1a., the array is...

But I want:

In initialization step 1a, the array is...

Is there a way to tell latex to drop the period from the reference?

Comment: Could you make the example complete, with the documentclass and the `usepackage` statements? That would make the exact conditions of your question more clear, which helps in finding an answer, and it would also help in making it faster to reproduce and start thinking about an answer without have to add extra code.

Comment: I completed the code snippet to a full working sample. It has all the packages I use in the actual document.

Comment: It is much clearer now. You can use the `ref` argument for `setlist`, for example `label=\arabic*., ref=\arabic*`. See the `enumitem` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) page 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `enumitem` has a `ref` key, which allows you to format references differently from the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% enumitem list setup
\newlist{pseudocode}{enumerate}{2}% allow two levels of nesting in an enumerate-like environment
\setlist[pseudocode]{nosep}% compact spacing for all nesting levels
\setlist[pseudocode,1]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}% labels for top level
\setlist[pseudocode,2]{label=\arabic{pseudocodei}\alph*.,ref=\arabic{pseudocodei}\alph*}% labels for second level
\begin{document}


\section{Pseudocode}
\begin{pseudocode}
  \item Initialization
  \begin{pseudocode}
    \item Initialization step \label{initStep1}
    \item Another initialization step
  \end{pseudocode}
  \item Loop
\end{pseudocode}

\section{What does it do?}
In initialization step \ref{initStep1}, the array is...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! @alan-munn